# Uploading to different folders depending on choice - Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I've been reading the django documentation and I'm trying to create a set of choices. Depending on which choice a user chooses, a file will save in a different folder. Though I can't seem to find a way for this to work.

I've currently got this as my model:

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):

    Name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)

    Week_1 = 'Week1'
    Week_2 = 'Week2'
    Week_3 = 'Week3'
    Week_4 = 'Week4'

    Weekly_Choices = (
        (Week_1, 'Week_1'),
        (Week_2, 'Week_2'),
        (Week_2, 'Week_3'),
        (Week_2, 'Week_4')
    )

    Week = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Weekly_Choices, default=Week_1, blank=False)
    docfile = models.FileField()

    if Week.choices == Week_1:
        docfile.upload_to = 'documents/'+ Week_1 + '/' + 'Mentee'
```

Though, I don't know why this doesn't work - sorry I'm still a bit new to Django and Python.

I've looked into it more and I know there is a Model.get_FOO_display() function but that's not what im looking for. In addition I also looked at django-choices, though the 'get_choice' function outputs a dictionary type. I was hoping there might be an easier way which im missing?

Any help would be useful - thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
def choices_location(instance, filename):
     if instance.week == 'Week_1':
        return os.path.join('documents', 'Week_1','Mentee', filename)
     elif  instance.week == Week_2:
        return os.path.join('documents', 'Week_2','Mentee', filename)

docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=choices_location)
```

*This will work for you !*

Comment: That makes sense but the only issue I have is that it says "NameError: name 'Week' is not defined." I've put the function after I defined Week, though not sure why its saying name error

Answer (score 0):

it won't work unless you give a upload_to field in your modal field docfile

try this

```
docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=location)

def location(instance, filename):
    if instance.Week == Week_1:
       return 'documents/'+ Week_1 + '/' + 'Mentee' + filename
```

hope this helps you out